# Output line repeats using while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am just beginning to learn Java and still getting used to while loops. I would like the output statement to only show once instead of multiple times. For example, the statement should say:
"Even integers between 1 and 5 are: 2 4"

instead of:
"Even integers between 1 and 5 are: 
2
Even integers between 1 and 5 are: 
Even integers between 1 and 5 are: 
4"

If I could get some feedback on what I'm doing wrong here, it'd be appreciated. Thanks

```
//Declare variables 
int n1, n2, sumOdd = 0;
int sum = 0; 
int sumSquares = 0;

//Part B
int count = n1;
while (count < n2)
{    
    if (count % 2 ==0)
    {
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    count++;
    System.out.println("Even integers between " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " are: ");
} //end loop
```

Comment: Move the print statement outside (and after) the `while` loop.  Also, you're going to need to use either an array or collection to cache the matching numbers until you are ready to print them.

Answer (score 2):

create an int array or Collection before your loop, when you find out the even number in while loop, append the number in the array/collection.

After the `while` loop, print output only once, of course with those found numbers.

I think it is straightforward, and I leave the implementation part to you.

Answer (score 1):

You should take last part of the while loop out of it:

```
//Part B
  System.out.println("Even integers between " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " are: ");
  int count = n1;
  while (count < n2) {    
     if (count % 2 ==0) {
        System.out.print(" " + count);
     }
     count++;
  }
```

As you didn't mention that you want a comma between even numbers, then replacing `println` with `print` should be enough

Comment: I won't do in this way, even though for normal case, it works too. Since the first line is anyway printed out, it is not so nice for error/exception handling requirements. Or some other requirements come, like, print the total count of found numbers... etc.

Comment: You're right @Kent, but I believe that in this case it is sufficient for a beginner to get some experience of how to work with loops and their results.

Answer (score 0):

They are different ways to achieve your goal. A quick solution would be to put

`System.out.println("Even integers between " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " are: ");`

in front of your while-loop and and replace System.println() with System.print().

Answer (score 0):

```
int n1, n2, sumOdd = 0;  
int sum = 0;   
int sumSquares = 0;  
System.out.print("Even integers between " + n1 + " and " + n2 + " are: ");

//Part B
int count = n1;
while (count < n2)
{    
    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.print(count);
    }
    count++;
} //end loop
```

Comment: You should add a little explanation, as the OP is clearly a beginner